# Limit editor tab file name characters in PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm

How can I limit number of characters shown for editor tabs. (Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UWAHN.jpg)

[image]

Comment: I believe such feature has been removed: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-136069. If you enable `Editor > General > Editor Tabs > Hide tabs if there is no space` then tabs will get smaller if they will start not fitting the screen. But for one/two opened tabs with long file names (like on your screenshot) it will do nothing.

Comment: Thx lazyOne. Before upgrade to Phpstorm 9, I've used it and it works like a charm. But after upgrade, settings for tab title limit has gone. It was a great option and too sad no more tab title truncation. Using your solution now helped me. I hate to scroll to find proper tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such feature (max characters from file name to show in tab title) has been [removed recently](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-136069).

Right now if you enable `Settings (Preferences on Mac) | Editor | General | Editor Tabs | Hide tabs if there is no space` then tabs will get smaller if they will start not fitting the screen. But for one/two opened tabs with long file names (like on your screenshot) it will do nothing.

Comment: Thanks. It saved a lot of time.